# Check required for wraparound of osKernalSysTick()?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, keil

I am following Keil's [CMSIS-RTOS Tutorial](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTX/CMSIS_RTOS_Tutorial.pdf). It provides the following method to put sub-millisecond delays :

> ***Section: Sub millisecond delays***
>
> ```
> int32_t tick,delayPeriod;
> tick = osKernelSysTick(); // get start value of the Kernel system tick
> // Then we can scale a period in microseconds to a SysTick count value
> delayPeriod = osKernelTickMicroSec(100));
> // This then allows us to create a delay for the the required period.
> do { // Delay for 100 microseconds 
> } while ((osKernelSysTick() - tick) < delayPeriod);
> ```

The osKernelSysTick() returns the value of a rolling 32 bit counter; this implementation does not cater for the wraparound of that value.

If wraparound happens, then the intended delay would not be achieved. Is this a bug in official Keil documentation or am I missing something?

Comment: _"this implementation does not cater the wraparound of that value"_ - are you sure about that? Try working through the maths for the wraparound case, bearing in mind two's complement arithmetic.

Comment: @Muhammad - To complicate matters, you also have to worry about the optimizer taking the optimization and/or removing the undefined behavior shown above. They could have avoided a lot of the additional troubles by using a `uint32_t`. Also see Ian Lance Taylor's blog on [Signed Overflow](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120). And keep in mind *signed integer overflow* is undefined behavior, while *unsigned integer wrap* is well defined behavior.

Comment: The function prototype is `uint32_t osKernelSysTick(void )` It returns a unsigned value. Variable `ticks` type should be changed.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation you show does not cater for the wraparound because of the way the arithmetic is done.

```
do { // Delay for 100 microseconds 
} while ((osKernelSysTick() - tick) < delayPeriod);
```

This can cause arithmetic overflow when the timer wraps.

If you use an `unsigned` variable and compute the elasped time *before* comparing it with the required period, you will avoid this. Unsigned variables are guaranteed by the C standard to wrap.

```
uint32_t tick, delayPeriod, elapsed;            // unsigned
tick = osKernelSysTick();
delayPeriod = osKernelTickMicroSec(100));

do {
    elapsed = osKernelSysTick() - tick;         // separate arithmetic wraps cleanly
} while (elapsed < delayPeriod);
```

Note the function is defined as `uint32_t osKernelSysTick` anyway, so the original example is incorrect in using signed types.

Comment: What's wrong with a bit of implementation-defined (_not_ undefined) behaviour? Sure, perhaps it's a bit sloppy from a language-lawyer point of view, but "portable embedded code" is an oxymoron if ever there was one. [The implementation this code is written for](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125009767.htm) guarantees two's complement (as would any other implementation for the target platform), so the initial assignment of something greater than `INT_MAX` to `tick` is predictable, then everything subsequent falls out in the wash...

Comment: There's certainly no need for an explicit intermediate variable, because either everything's representable as `int` already, or it all gets automatically promoted to unsigned via the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: @Notlikethat the separation prevents any confusion between the arithmetic overflow and the comparison. And as I already explained, `int` is the wrong type, since overflow is undefined.

Comment: It is _not_ undefined. It is implementation-defined, and the implementation defines it in the sensible way. C99 6.3.1.3: "Otherwise,  the  new type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: @Notlikethat using `signed` integers, even *without* arithmetic overflow in the comparison, `-2147483500 - 100`, for example, can be less than the target interval, because it is negative (stretching the numbers to prove a point).

Comment: But that could never happen, because [`osKernelSysTick()` returns a `uint32_t`](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS/html/group___c_m_s_i_s___r_t_o_s___kernel_ctrl.html#gad0262e4688e95d1e9038afd9bcc16001).

Comment: @Notlikethat look at the code posted. It uses `int32_t` which as I said, is wrong. And read my answer properly, where I said what you just did.

Comment: @Notlikethat the reason I posted this answer is because I have been there and fallen into the trap where *occasionally* the loop fails. Not with this compiler, which may generate code that does not fail, but in the general case, my simple solution is *guaranteed* to work. Just because not all code is portable on embedded devices is no excuse for the sloppiness where you started, when it is ***easy*** to make it bullet proof, without waiting to see if there is a rare failure, so hard to catch, that messes the program, and might only come to light once the product has gone to market.

Comment: I'm not actually in disagreement with your overall point, only the use of "incorrect", "undefined", "wrong", etc. because they're simply not true, and I refuse to stand for misinformation. The irrefutable answer to "is this a bug or am I missing something?" would be "no - here's the horribly subtle reason why it does actually work, but here's also the sensible way you _should_ do it", but for covering the most valuable latter aspect, and my further silence on the matter, have an upvote ;)